# measure width of multi-line math code

Tags: math-mode, width

I would like to measure the width of multi-line math code.
My approach below does not always succeed.
In the second example an additional line break is inserted: I believe that it has to do with the space produced around the \wedge symbol.
I guess that an entirely different approach may be required?
I appreciate any suggestions.

Cheers

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\mpbox@length}
\newcommand{\mpbox}[1]{%
\settowidth{\mpbox@length}{$\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{array}$}%
\parbox[t]{\mpbox@length}{$#1$}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}

\begin{document}

\noindent ExampleA
% expected result except for the overly wide box
\noindent\fbox{\parbox[t]{5cm}{$\wedge w$}}\\
% correctly computed width
\noindent \fbox{\mpbox{\wedge w}}\\

\noindent ExampleB
% expected result except for the overly wide box
\noindent\fbox{\parbox[t]{5cm}{$w\\\wedge w$}}\\
% incorrectly computed width resulting in an additional linebreak
\noindent \fbox{\mpbox{w\\\wedge w}}\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `varwidth` to the rescue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mpbox}[1]{%
  \begin{varwidth}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}%
    $#1$%
  \end{varwidth}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}

\begin{document}

\noindent ExampleA
% expected result except for the overly wide box
\noindent\fbox{\parbox[t]{5cm}{$\wedge w$}}\\
% correctly computed width
\noindent \fbox{\mpbox{\wedge w}}

\noindent ExampleB
% expected result except for the overly wide box
\noindent\fbox{\parbox[t]{5cm}{$w\\\wedge w$}}\\
% correctly computed width
\noindent \fbox{\mpbox{w\\\wedge w}}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remark:**

Environment `varwidth` will decrease the width automatically to the actual used maximal line width. Since you want to put the result inside a `\fbox` I have decreased the maximal line width specification to leave room for the frame in case of overlong lines.